# How can I check a Python unicode string to see that it *actually* is proper Unicode?

Tags: python, postgresql, unicode

So I have this page:

http://hub.iis.sinica.edu.tw/cytoHubba/

Apparently it's all kinds of messed up, as it gets decoded properly but when I try to save it in postgres I get:

```
DatabaseError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xedbdbf
```

The database clams up after that and refuses to do anything without a rollback, which will be a bit hard to issue (long story). Is there a way for me to check if this will happen before it hits the database? source.encode("utf-8") works without a hitch, so I'm not sure what's going on...

Comment: Are you sure that your connection is set to use UTF-8?

Comment: Yep, 300,000 other webpages were added just fine, it's just this one that fails...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a **bug** in python 2.x that is only fixed python 3.x.  In fact, this bug is even in OS X's iconv (but not the glibc one).

Here's what's happening:

Python 2.x does not recognize UTF8 surrogate pairs [1] as being invalid (which is what your character sequence is)

This *should* be all that's needed:

```
foo.decode('utf8').encode('utf8')
```

But thanks to that bug they're not fixing, it doesn't catch surrogate pairs.

Try this in python 2.x and then in 3.x:

```
b'\xed\xbd\xbf'.decode('utf8')
```

It will throw an error (correctly) in the latter.  They aren't fixing it in the 2.x branch either.  See [2] and [3] for more info

[1] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#section-4

[2] http://bugs.python.org/issue9133

[3] http://bugs.python.org/issue8271#msg102209

Comment: No problem.  I was trying to do more or less what you were doing to filter my data when doing a COPY into postgres.  What I ended up doing was just letting it fail and filtering out individual rows based on the error outputs.  It was based off the general idea of how the copy code in pgloader works http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgloader/

Comment: unrelated: if you want to fix the surrogate pairs: `u'[\ud83d\ude42]'.encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf-16') = u'[\U0001f642]'`

Answer (score 1):

A Python `unicode` object is a sequence of Unicode codepoints and by definition proper unicode. A python `str` string is a sequence of bytes that might be Unicode characters encoded with a certain encoding (UTF-8, Latin-1, Big5,...).

The first question there is if `source` is a `unicode` object or a `str` string.
That `source.encode("utf-8")` works just means that you *can* convert `source` to a UTF-8 encoded string, but are you doing it before you pass it to the database function? The database seems to expect it's inputs to be encoded with UTF-8, and complains that the equivalent of `source.decode("utf-8")` fails.

If `source` is a `unicode` object, it should be encoded to UTF-8 before you pass it to the database:

```
source = u'abc'
call_db(source.encode('utf-8'))
```

If `source` is a `str` encoded as something else than Utf-8, you should decode that encoding and then encode the resulting Unicode object to UTF-8:

```
source = 'abc'
call_db(source.decode('Big5').encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. source is a unicode object which gets encoded fine in Python, things break when I try to send it to postgres...

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you doing? The content does indeed decode fine as `utf-8`:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> webcontent = urllib.urlopen("http://hub.iis.sinica.edu.tw/cytoHubba/").read()
>>> unicodecontent = webcontent.decode("utf-8")
>>> type(webcontent)
<type 'str'>
>>> type(unicodecontent)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> type(unicodecontent.encode("utf-8"))
<type 'str'>
```

Make sure you understand the difference between Unicode strings and utf-8 encoded strings, though. What you need to send to the database is `unicodecontent.encode("utf-8")` (which is the same as `webcontent`, but you decoded to verify that you **don't** have invalid byte sequences in your source).

I'd indeed as WoLpH says check the settings on the database and the database connection.

Comment: I'm using Django, which encodes everything properly, but it's postgres that's deciding that the encoding (or encoded string) is bad, for some reason... Everything I do in Python works, that's why I can't detect it. Maybe it's a postgres bug?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I opted to just work around this, catch the error and rollback the transaction using Django's transaction management. I'm mystified as to why it would happen, though...

Answer (score 0):

To solve my similar problems with django/postgress I now do something like this

```
class SafeTextField(models.TextField)
    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        encoded = base64.encodestring(value).strip()
        return super(SafeTextField, self).get_prep_value(encoded)
    def to_python(self, value):
        decoded = base64.decodestring(value)
        return super(SafeTextField, self).to_python(decoded)
```