# How to do surrogateescape in python2

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x, surrogate-pairs

Python3 changed the unicode behaviour to deny surrogate pairs while python2 not.

There's a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3510831/543492)

But it do not supply a solution on how to remove surrogate pairs in python2 or how to do surrogate escape.

Python3 example:

```
>>> a = b'\xed\xa0\xbd\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd'
>>> a.decode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape')
'\udced\udca0\udcbd你好'
>>> a.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
'你好'
```

The '\xed\xa0\xbd' here is not proper utf-8 chars. And I want to ignore them or escape them.

Is it possible to do the same thing in python2?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?  It is not clear.  Provide an example.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I have added an example.

Comment: I don't see a better way than post-processing the decoded unicode object to remove all characters between '\udc00' and '\udfff'.

Comment: @ArminRigo do you have any reference for '\udc00' and '\udfff'? Why are them the boundary?

Comment: They are the "high surrogates".  See anywhere, e.g. on Wikipedia.  I can only side with Mark: it's not clear what you want to do.  Do you want equivalent code to do the same as Python 3's decode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape') and decode('utf-8', 'ignore'), but in Python 2?

Comment: @ArminRigo yes, it is.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no built-in solution.  You need to write a function that looks over each character (say of the resulting unicode), looks up which ones are surrogates, and replace them as you need, in order to emulate the behavior that you need.

Comment: @lxyu did you find an answer on how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

There is no builtin solution, but there is an implementation of surrogateescapes in python-future:
https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future

Add `from future.utils.surrogateescape import register_surrogateescape` to the imports. Then call the method `register_surrogateescape()` and then you can use the `errors='surrogateescape'` error handler in `encode` and `decode`.

An example can be found [here](https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/issues/116)